# Google script: search and replace the url of linked text in a Doc (not sheet)

Tags: url, google-apps-script, replace, google-docs

I am trying to search-and-replace linked text from an old url to a new url.

It is not working and I have spent hours and hours. If I remove the "if (found)" it gives me "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElement' of null" even though my files have text that is linked to this old_url.

Please, help me.

```
function myFunction() {
  var old_url  ="http://hurlx1.com";
  var new_url  ="http://urlxa.com";
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("my folder id").getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS);

  while (files.hasNext()) {
     var file = files.next();
     var doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.getId());
     found=doc.getBody().findText(old_url); 

     if (found) {
         var link_element = found.getElement().asText();
         var start = found.getStartOffset();
         var end = found.getEndOffsetInclusive();
         var correct_link = link_element.getText().slice(start, end);
         link_element.setLinkUrl(start, end, correct_link);
       }
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe your situation and goal as follows.

- In your Google Document,

  - Text and hyperlink are the same with `old_url`.
  - Hyperlink is `old_url`. But the text is different from `old_url`.
- You want to update `old_url` with `new_url` using Google Apps Script.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- About your error message, when the text of `old_url` is not found in the Google Document with `found=doc.getBody().findText(old_url);`, `found` becomes `null` even when `old_url` is set as the hyperlink. Because `findText` searches the text on Document body, and that cannot search the hyperlinks set to the texts. I think that this is the reason of your issue.
- In your script, `var new_url ="http://urlxa.com";` is used. But when the link is set, `correct_link` is used like `link_element.setLinkUrl(start, end, correct_link);`. By this, `new_url` is not set.
- When you want to update the text of `http://hurlx1.com` to `new_url` of `var new_url ="http://urlxa.com";`, it is required to also modify the text.
- In your script, only the 1st `old_url` is updated. If there are several values of `old_url` in the Document, it is required to update them using the loop.

#### Specification of modified script:

This modified script can be used for the following patterns.

- Text and hyperlink are the same with `old_url`.

  - In this case, the text value of `old_url` is also updated with `old_url`.
- Hyperlink is `old_url`. But the text is different from `old_url`.

  - In this case, only the hyperlink of `old_url` is updated.
- There are several texts with the hyperlink of `old_url` in the Google Document.

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var old_url  ="http://hurlx1.com";
  var new_url  ="http://urlxa.com";
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("my folder id").getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS);

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.getId());
    var body = doc.getBody();

    // The following script is used for the situation that the text and hyperlink are the same with `old_url`.
    var found = body.findText(old_url);
    while (found) {
      var link_element = found.getElement().asText();
      var start = found.getStartOffset();
      var end = found.getEndOffsetInclusive();
      var correct_link = link_element.getText().slice(start, end);
      link_element.setLinkUrl(start, end, new_url).replaceText(old_url, new_url);
      found = body.findText(old_url, found);
    }

    // The following script is used for the situation that although the hyperlink is `old_url`, the text is different from `old_url`.
    var text = body.editAsText();
    for (var i = 0; i < text.getText().length; i++) {
      if (text.getLinkUrl(i) == old_url) {
        text.setLinkUrl(i, i + 1, new_url);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### References:

- [replaceText(searchPattern, replacement)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#replacetextsearchpattern,-replacement)
- [findText(searchPattern, from)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#findtextsearchpattern,-from)
- [editAsText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#editastext)

Comment: Tanaike, amazing. I am so grateful for your help. Thank you so much.

Comment: This is such a great answer! Well documented, and the final lines on "editAsText" are most helpful. One question: why `i+1`? It is endOffsetInclusive so `i` seems better?

Comment: @WillemS Thank you for your comment. In that case, as one method, the text is checked every character. By this, I used `startOffset` and `endOffsetInclusive` of `i` and `i + 1` for scanning the text and giving the hyperlink every character. For example, I think the following flow can be also used. 1. Values of `startOffset` and `endOffsetInclusive` are retrieved from the text. 2. As 2nd step, `setLinkUrl` is used using the values. If I misunderstood your comment, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike My remark was meant about your line `text.setLinkUrl(i, i + 1, new_url);` This resulted in a whitespace after each hyperlinked word. I changed it to `text.setLinkUrl(i, i, new_url);` and it works like a charm.